# Get CString from CString reference?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, smart-device

Here is my code

```
CInternetSession session(L"My Session");
CHttpConnection *pHttpCon ;
CHttpFile *filedat = NULL;
pHttpCon = session.GetHttpConnection((LPCTSTR)Url_server, (INTERNET_PORT)1040, (LPCTSTR)username, (LPCTSTR)password);
    filedat = pHttpCon->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_GET, "");
    filedat->SendRequest();
CString line;
while(filedat->ReadString(line)) {
      printf("Line : %s ",(LPCTSTR)line);
      printf("\n Line Length : %d ",line.GetLength());
}
```

Problem is the String Read is "file1.name=201304" and length is 9
It should be 17 or more. Can any buddy tell me what may be the problem???

```
   String Read                                  Showing Length
 "file1.size=16"                                     7                        
 "file1.time=2013/02/28 Thu 10:36:32"                17
 "file1.name=201304"                                 9
```

Comment: If the length you expect is 17 and the length you get is 9, what is the *content* of that 9 character string? Is it the first 9 chars of what you expect?

Comment: NO. Content is "file1.name=201304"..

Comment: So, you are saying that `CString::GetLength()` gives the wrong value?

Comment: Yes,. It gives length correctly if i manually assign String value to that variable.. But here its assigned from CHttpFile::ReadString..

Comment: Are you reading more than 1 string? Your `printf` writes two lines but only one `\n` - are you sure you're reading the output correctly?

Comment: The String it read n displayed is correct but calculated length is not. I don't know much about VC++ but i think problem is in assigning value to that variable because CHttpFile::ReadString takes CString reference as argument..

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work:

```
while(filedat->ReadString(line)) 
{
/* Original code
  printf("Line : %s ",(LPCTSTR)line);
  printf("\n Line Length : %d ",line.GetLength());
*/
  _tprintf(L"%s\n", (LPCTSTR)line);
  _tprintf(L"Line Length: %d\n\n", line.GetLength());
}
```